# VBA - assinging values through for loop

Tags: excel, vba

Is there a more efficient way of handling the below?

```
                    Range("approvedSales").Cells(raS, 2).Value = Sheet1.Cells(i, 1).Value
                    Range("approvedSales").Cells(raS, 3).Value = Sheet1.Cells(i, 4).Value
                    Range("approvedSales").Cells(raS, 4).Value = Sheet1.Cells(i, 6).Value
                    Range("approvedSales").Cells(raS, 5).Value = Sheet1.Cells(i, 7).Value
                    Range("approvedSales").Cells(raS, 6).Value = Sheet1.Cells(i, 9).Value
                    Range("approvedSales").Cells(raS, 7).Value = Sheet1.Cells(i, 26).Value
                    Range("approvedSales").Cells(raS, 8).Value = Sheet1.Cells(i, 27).Value
                    Range("approvedSales").Cells(raS, 9).Value = Sheet1.Cells(i, 16).Value
                    Range("approvedSales").Cells(raS, 10).Value = Sheet1.Cells(i, 17).Value
                    Range("approvedSales").Cells(raS, 11).Value = Sheet1.Cells(i, 18).Value
                    Range("approvedSales").Cells(raS, 12).Value = Sheet1.Cells(i, 19).Value
                    raS = raS + 1
```

Comment: since `(i, 1)` and `(i, 4)` values are not consistent, it makes your question very unclear. Where is the 2nd value coming from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "cleaner" way to do this is to store your values in `Array`s instead:

```
Dim array1() As Variant, array2() As Variant, i As Integer
array1 = Array(2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12)
array2 = Array(1, 4, 6, 7, 9, 26, 27, 16, 17, 18, 19)

For i = 0 To 10
    Range("approvedSales").Cells(raS, array1(i)).Value = Sheet1.Cells(i, array2(i)).Value
Next i
```

Comment: What I was looking for. TY!